# tar: Cannot create symlink to XXXX: Operation not permitted

Tags: tar, symlink

**The context:** I am on an Ubuntu VM (VirtualBox).  I created the VM with limited disk space.  My use of it has evolved beyond what I initially envisioned.  I am using a large footprint analysis/design environment (Matlab) which allows me to deploy applications written in its language.  These apps can run on other platforms if the correct Runtime is installed.  In this development cycle, I find myself switching between different versions of Matlab and their associated Runtimes.  Because of the small virtual disk, I am uninstalling a version of Matlab or a version of its Runtime in order to install something else.  The installation takes place over the internet, and unfortunately, I have modest bandwidth meant for home use.

Instead of uninstalling and re-installing, I tried to save time by temporary swapping out a Runtime and storing it in the much larger disk of the host Windows OS.  If we assume that the host OS user's home folder is mounted as /media/sf_HostOSusr and the Runtime folder tree is rooted at /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v912:

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/
tar czf \
/media/sf_HostOSusr/VendorApp/matlab/20230425.1502%usr%local%MATLAB%MATLAB_Runtime%V912.tgz \
v912
```

I get several dozen errors:

```
tar: v912/bin/glnxa64/libmwfftw3f_mpi.so.3: Cannot create symlink to ‘libmwfftw3f_mpi.so.3.5.8’: Operation not permitted
tar: v912/bin/glnxa64/libPDFRes.so.7: Cannot create symlink to ‘libPDFRes.so.7.1’: Operation not permitted
tar: v912/bin/glnxa64/libmwfftw3f.so.3: Cannot create symlink to ‘libmwfftw3f.so.3.5.8’: Operation not permitted
<...snip...>
tar: v912/runtime/glnxa64/libmwmclmcrrt.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.12’: Operation not permitted
tar: v912/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjsig.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘../libjsig.so’: Operation not permitted
tar: v912/bin/glnxa64/libMatlabDataArray.so: Cannot create symlink to ‘../../extern/bin/glnxa64/libMatlabDataArray.so’: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Most of these symbolic links are to files existing in the same directory.  I didn't think that it is due to incompatibilities with the host Windows 10 (64-bit) file system, since the tar'd up content is encapsulated within a tar ball.  **What are some other reasons for such symlink problems in creating a tar ball?**

I tried archiving one symlink and its target from above, which didn't result in any symlink errors:

```
cd v912/runtime/glnxa64/
tar czf /media/sf_HostOSusr/tmp/Test.zip libmwmclmcrrt.so libmwmclmcrrt.so.9.12
```

Comment: Have you tried giving -h to tar ? That will try to dereference those links.
The error might be because symlinks are not supported on your Windows partition format.

Comment: @amisax: Thanks, but I don't want to dereference those links.  That will inflate the file tree size by a lot.  It is plausible that there are many more links than errors.  I think it's remotely possible that the errors are due to symlinks not being supported on the Windows host OS.  Since the host OS file system only stores the binary tar ball, which is further encapsulated in a gzip archive, I can't see how the OS would have access to the symlinks in order to mess with them.  That's why I'm trying to fathom other causes. I've already deleted the file tree, but this won't be the last time.

Comment: Though the -h option would be a good troubleshooting step when I have to do this again.  I'm not sure how likely it is to reveal anything, as I already tried creating a *.tgz archive of a single symlink and its target (tail end of the originally posted question).